# Как правильно организовать email рассылку

Tags: email, sendmail

Всем привет.
Есть база email порядка 30 000 000, нужно сделать рассылку. Подскажите, как правильно сделать рассылку, чтобы не попасть в черный список, какие есть ограничения на отправку, одним словом, как это правильно сделать?

Comment: 1. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=ru 2. https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/rules/info 3. https://yandex.ru/support/mail-new/web/spam/honest-mailers.html

Answer (score 2):

В первом комментарии Вам дали правильные ссылки и их надо все изучить.
Из личного опыта не спама, но самостоятельных коммерческих рассылок: нюансов очень много.

1. Чисто технические нюансы: правильные и действительные PTR и SPF записи, настроенная DKIM-подпись, отсутствие (изначально) домена и ip адреса в блэк-листах, указание в письмах заголовка `list-unsubscribe` и `Precedence: bulk (junk, list, list-unsubscribe и т. п.)`, отправка писем только через SMTP.
2. Требования к домену тоже существуют: возраст от года, но чем старше, тем лучше,

> (Обяз.) Хост, осуществляющий рассылку, должен иметь постоянный IP-адрес с корректно настроенным обратным DNS-запросом. При этом регистрационные данные владельца домена должны быть актуальными и доступными публично по протоколу WHOIS.
>
> Для корректной идентификации доменное имя должно быть содержательным, а не являться автоматическим адресом наподобие x.y.z.w-in-addr-arpa или dsl-4-3-2-1.provider.net.

Делать рассылки лучше с поддоменов (promo.example.com, info.example.com), соответственно использовать почтовые адреса отправителя с этих поддоменов. Домен должен иметь хорошую почтовую репутацию, например, можно перед основной рассылкой в течении недели разослать несколько десятков тысяч писем по небольшой надежной базе подписчиков, с малым процентом отказов ("прогреть" домен).

3. К письмам тоже много требований: одно письмо - один получатель, в письме обязательно должна быть возможность отписаться от рассылки, в теле письма должен быть указан в явном виде email получателя (а-ля Вы получили письмо на электронный адрес example@example.com так как...), письма в формате html с соблюдением кодировки и MIME типов, нельзя использовать сокращатели ссылок. Очень желательно, чтобы письма были персонализированными, как тема письма, так и тело, а не полностью идентичными. Самые простые варианты - использовать имя получателя в письме (из базы подписчиков), разные приветствия, в зависимости от времени отправления письма, указание города или региона подписчика (если есть в базе) и т.п.. Не использовать в письмах "стоп слова" спам фильтров и изображения с форматом популярных рекламных баннеров.

Очень важно: слать письма надо только с разрешения подписчика, на его проверенный email, не тот который он только указал, но и подтвердил, например переходом по ссылке отправленной на него! Почему это важно: после определенного количества отказов от рассылки (специфично для каждого почтового сервиса) все письма пойдут в спам, многие посчитали письмо спамом (а иногда людям проще ткнуть кнопку спам, чем отписываться от рассылки) все письма пойдут в спам, отправили подряд несколько писем на несуществующие, заблокированные ящики - получили бан на домен, пока перед саппортом почтовика не "изивинитесь".

Перед запуском рассылки надо проверить качество отправляемого письма, я пользуюсь этим [сервисом](http://vpsvds.ru/blog/2015/11/07/proverka-pisem-na-spam.html) . Советую зарегистрироваться в Кабинете почтового мастера на распространенных почтовых сервисах: [Яндекс](https://postmaster.yandex.ru/) , [Мэйл](https://postmaster.mail.ru/), [Google](https://postmaster.google.com). Там Вы сможете смотреть подробную статистику рассылок, получать уведомления и рекомендации. Очень удобно и информативно.

Лично мое мнение: если бы мне надо было сейчас разослать 30 млн писем, я бы делал это частями, например 100 разных рассылок по 300 тыс с десятка почтовых серверов.